# How to make a D pad for a android game

Tags: android

Hi can anyone I am trying to make a game that uses a dpad. I have been playing gmaes that have them but can't find any good reference's. Am I wrong to be trying to create buttons to do this? I am new to android.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of game engines have provisions for d-pads, I think http://www.andengine.org has one.